# Polymorphic JSON Deserialization failing using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON to various sub-classes using a custom `JsonConverter`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19308474/1351298) almost to the point.

My abstract base-class:

```
abstract class MenuItem
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Contents { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Submenus { get; set; }
    public String Source { get; set; }
    public String SourceType { get; set; }
    public abstract void DisplayContents();
}
```

And my derived `JsonConverter`:

```
class MenuItemConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(MenuItem).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
            switch (item["SourceType"].Value<String>())
            {
                case SourceType.File:    return item.ToObject<Menu.FileMenu>();
                case SourceType.Folder:  return item.ToObject<Menu.FolderMenu>();
                case SourceType.Json:    return item.ToObject<Menu.JsonMenu>();
                case SourceType.RestGet: return item.ToObject<Menu.RestMenu>();
                case SourceType.Rss:     return item.ToObject<Menu.RssMenu>();
                case SourceType.Text:    return item.ToObject<Menu.TextMenu>();
                case SourceType.Url:     return item.ToObject<Menu.UrlMenu>();
                default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid source type");
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

`SourceType` is just a static class holding some string constants.

The JSON file is deserialized like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuItem>(File.ReadAllText(menuPath), new MenuItemConverter());
```

Now, my issue is that whenever I run the code I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not create an instance of type ConsoleMenu.Model.MenuItem. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Submenus[0].Title', line 5, position 21.
```

The Json file in question looks like this:

```
{
    "Title": "Main Menu",
    "Submenus": [
        {
            "Title": "Submenu 1",
            "Contents": "This is an example of the first sub-menu",
            "SourceType": "Text"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Submenu 2",
            "Contents": "This is the second sub-menu",
            "SourceType": "Text"
        },
        {
            "Title": "GitHub System Status",
            "Contents": "{\"status\":\"ERROR\",\"body\":\"If you see this, the data failed to load\"}",
            "Source": "https://status.github.com/api/last-message.json",
            "SourceType": "RestGet"
        },
        {
            "Title": "TF2 Blog RSS",
            "Contents": "If you see this message, an error has occurred",
            "Source": "http://www.teamfortress.com/rss.xml",
            "SourceType": "Rss"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Submenus Test",
            "Contents": "Testing the submenu functionality",
            "Submenus": [
                {
                    "Title": "Submenu 1",
                    "Contents": "This is an example of the first sub-menu",
                    "SourceType": "Text"
                },
                {
                    "Title": "Submenu 2",
                    "Contents": "This is the second sub-menu",
                    "SourceType": "Text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "SourceType": "Text"
}
```

It appears to me that it has trouble deserializing the nested objects, how do I get around that?

Comment: I found that I got exactly the same error if I used the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and passed a serializer settings with my converter added. When I used the same overload as you it worked... I don't know whether this is the JsonSerializer at fault or my understanding of the serializer settings.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Firstly, `SourceType` is missed for menu item "Submenus Test" in your json.

Secondly, you shouldn't simply use `ToObject` because of the `Submenus` property, which should be handled recursively.

The following `ReadJson` will work:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
    var sourceType = jObject["SourceType"].Value<string>();

    object target = null;

    switch (sourceType)
    {
        case SourceType.File: 
            target = new FileMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.Folder: 
            target = new FolderMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.Json: 
            target = new JsonMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.RestGet: 
            target = new RestMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.Rss: 
            target = new RssMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.Text: 
            target = new TextMenu(); break;
        case SourceType.Url: 
            target = new UrlMenu(); break;
        default: 
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid source type");
    }

    serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

    return target;
}
```

Comment: I was gonna do your "btw" after I got this to work, the original code didn't have polymorphism, but I decided to extend it to modularise the functionality

Comment: I deleted that "btw". I just found your properties currently in the base `MenuItem` should be essential. :P

Comment: For others with a similar question, this works on any polymorphic deserialization of an abstract class as well. I was getting a StackOverflowException prior without a self-referential structure because jObject.ToObject(targetType) would recursively send me back in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because your `MenuItem` class is **marked as `abstract`**. I am guessing you did this to enforce the implementation of the `DisplayContents()` method in inherited classes.

A different way of allowing the Json to be read, to what [Mouhong Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29124962/3864353) suggested, is to make a base `Interface` for your MenuItem structure, have your `MenuItem` class implement the interface with a basic version of the `DisplayContents()` method, mark it as virtual and then override it in your inherited subclasses.
This approach will ensure that you always will get something shown when calling `DisplayContents()` and remove the error that you are getting.

A very crude and simplified version of the classes and interface:

```
public interface IMenuItem
{
  String Title { get; set; }
  String Contents { get; set; }
  List<MenuItem> Submenus { get; set; }
  String Source { get; set; }
  String SourceType { get; set; }
  void DisplayContents();
}

public class MenuItem: IMenuItem
{
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public String Contents { get; set; }
  public List<MenuItem> Submenus { get; set; }
  public String Source { get; set; }
  public String SourceType { get; set; }
  public virtual void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Title); }
}

// Very very basic implementation of the classes, just to show what can be done
public class FileMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Title + this.GetType().ToString()); } }
public class FolderMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Title + "Folder Class"); } }
public class JsonMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Contents); } }
public class RestMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Source); } }
public class RssMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(SourceType); } }
public class TextMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Title); } }
public class UrlMenu : MenuItem { public override void DisplayContents() { MessageBox.Show(Title); } }
```