# newtonsoft json serializer for Abstract Classes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I've a concrete class below which inherits from abstract class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class MyAbstractClass { }
```

NewtonSoft JSON Serializer throws exception below when trying to de/serialize  MyconcreteClass class:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not create an
>   instance of type MyAbstractClass. Type is an interface or abstract
>   class and cannot be instantiated. Path ....

Did a bit of googling and found this setting below:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
                };
```

If I use above setting i.e. TypeNameHandling.All, the error goes away.

Questions in my mind:

1. Is this is the correct approach to fix this issue (And not sure what this option is not out of box)
2. Any performance or negative impacts that I should be aware of with this setting.

Thanks.

Comment: When using `TypeNameHandling` you need to validate the incoming types with a custom serialization binder, for security reasons.  See e.g. [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) for why.  For an alternative strategy see [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).

Comment: @dbc [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124126/polymorphic-json-deserialization-failing-using-json-net) is better because it fixes a bug in your second link if the json object is recursive.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Is this is the correct approach to fix this issue (And not sure what this option is not out of box)**
I think it's correct approach to to de/serialize inheritance class with NewtonSoft JSON. When we de/serialize with setting **TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All**, the .NET type name will always be included when serializing. Without the type information, it's hard for converter to decide which class will be de/serialized.

**2. Any performance or negative impacts that I should be aware of with this setting.**
As remarked in Json.NET Documentation, TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source and you should create a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than TypeNameHandling.None.
You could reference the following links
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm
https://mallibone.com/post/serialize-object-inheritance-with-json.net